# Binding Ctrl (-) in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an application with a Text widget, and I want my font to get smaller when the user presses the Control key and the minus key (-).

the code

```
self.bind_all("<Control-=>", self.increaseFont)
```

seems to work fine for getting the font to increase when the user presses the control key and the equals key, but the line

```
self.bind_all("<Control-->", self.decreaseFont)
```

does not seem to work.

When I try to run it, it gives me a runtime error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mathEditor.py", line 122, in <module>
    app = MathEditor(fileName = sys.argv[1])
  File "./mathEditor.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.bind_all("<Control-->", self.decreaseFont)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 997, in bind_all
    return self._bind(('bind', 'all'), sequence, func, add, 0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 940, in _bind
    self.tk.call(what + (sequence, cmd))
_tkinter.TclError: no event type or button # or keysym
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `self.bind_all("<Control-minus>", self.decreaseFont)`.